# AVAudioSession always returns the same outputVolume

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, watchkit, avaudiosession

I have an watchOS app that request the current volume from the iPhone parent app via:

```
 session?.sendMessage(["getVolume":1], replyHandler: {
                replyDict in
                    if let currentVolume = replyDict["currentVolume"] as? Float{
                        NSLog("Current volume received from phone with value: \(currentVolume)")
                    }
                }, errorHandler: {
                    (error) -> Void in
                    NSLog("Error: :\(error)")
                    // iOS app failed to get message. Send it in the background
                    //self.session?.transferUserInfo(["getVolume":1])
            })
```

The iPhone app handles it like this:

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void) {
        NSLog("Received a message")
        if let _ = message["getVolume"] as? Int{
       replyHandler(["currentVolume":AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume])
        }
        else{
            replyHandler([:])
        }
    }
```

This always returns the same outputVolume the phone had on the first request.

I investigated several things like if there is some kind of caching for the background request but it is always a new call that returns the new value.

Is there any workaround to get system volume with a different way or maybe a solution how to get this to work with `AVAudioSession`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an issue with the WatchKit or watchOS per se, as I've experienced this in a regular iOS application.

I had to activate my app's audio session in order to observe the change in volume:

```
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```

Comment: This has the downside that any audio from another app is muted which is not what I intend to do

Comment: @AzzUrr1 set an audio session category to not interfere with any other audio currently playing.

Comment: This worked! Thanks! Also need to add Audio Background Mode